# Windows script to move files on create

Tags: windows, shell, console

I want to write a Windows script (running in Windows 7) that runs every time when a new files has been created in a specified folder. It then checks weather the newly created file matches a certain naming convention and if so it moves it to a different folder.

How can I do the above?

Comment: What have you tried?  Also, be careful of moving too quickly, sometime things are still busy writing - re:FTP.

Comment: inotifywait, cron are 2 of the common options... EDIT: I had added this comment looking at bash tag. Updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't have to be immediately after the files are created, then maybe simple task, checking the folder with interval and using [`robocopy`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to move the files will suffice? This can be accomplished with Task Scheduler:

```
schtasks /create /sc minute /mo 3 /tn FileCopy /tr ROBOCOPY C:\source_folder c:\destination_folder some_file_name*.* /MOV

/sc - Specifies the schedule frequency
/mo - Refines the schedule type to allow finer control over schedule recurrence. In this case it just specifies how many minutes until the task is run again
/tn - Name for the task that will be visible in task scheduler
/tr - Task to be executed /rl
```

You can also append `/rl HIGHEST` if you need more privileges to complete the task, and `/ru SYSTEM` to execute as `SYSTEM` user (you'll need admin privilege for that), so there won't be any console windows popping out every time tasks executes.